# controlling a 8051 microcontroller through bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, 8051

My teacher wants to add Bluetooth communication to the electronic project in are school. He asked me to check out the possibility.

I tried googling, but I couldn't find anything I was sure about.

I am looking for a chip that fulfils the following conditions:

- Decodes and encodes bluetooth communication.
- Interfaced using RS-232 (anything else is acceptable, if you explain or give references for how to use it).
- Nothing too fancy.

It could be more than one chip.
**bonus:** A full data sheet of the chip.

The microprocessor we are using is [AT89C5131](http://www.atmel.com/devices/at89c5131.aspx).

Comment: Where does the 8051 come in vs. AT89C5131?

Comment: @jippie sorry, I didn't under stand what you are asking.

Comment: In your title you are writing about 8051, whereas in your question text you write about AT89C5131. What controller are you using?

Comment: I believe the AT89C5131 is the uP with a 8051 core ...

Comment: @jippie: If you [look it up](http://www.atmel.com/devices/at89c5131.aspx), you'll see that the AT89C5131 does indeed use the 8051 architecture. The solution he's looking for will probably be generic across all 8051-type chips.

Comment: Shopping, off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [spakrfun's bluetooth section](https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/115), i think you will find something to fit your need and quickly get a prototype out. plus they got data sheets and schematics available

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet is a Bluetooth to serial /  UART converter. They come at various prices, but interestingly all look alike.

[For example this random article found on a random search machine.](http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=324)